# Video in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

I have a video in avi form. I want to play it in MATLAB

Code that I am using is :

```
 videoFReader =       vision.VideoFileReader(song.avi) ;
 videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer ;
 while ~isDone(videoFReader)
 videoFrame = step(videoFReader)
 step(videoPlayer,videoFrame) ;
 end
 release(videoPlayer) ;
  release(videoFReader)
```

The video is playing but sound is not coming.

Comment: What OS are you using? And I assume you have quotes around your file name?

Comment: you need another argout: [Video,Audio] = step(videoFReader)

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do that in native MATLAB, but you can do it using the CV toolbox in Simulink... as you're already using stuff from the toolbox, you should be able to use the tools within Simulink.  Try: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/combine-video-and-audio-streams.html

Comment: @lanpa - Can you show us where you got that syntax from?  According to the MATLAB docs: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.videoplayer.step.html - Only video playback is supported.

Comment: @rayryeng http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.videofilereader-class.html